# Get data from sqlite3 in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I am creating a server that saves msgs into a database( sqlite3 )then send them to some clients, The question is how to get data from the database, by the way I am new into the sqlite3 API in C,here is some part of the code I Have:

```
snprintf( commands, 256, "SELECT Msg FROM %s WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN %ld AND %ld;",
        sn, ( serverTime - diff->tv_sec ), serverTime );

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, commands, -1, &res, 0 );

while( sqlite3_step( res ) == SQLITE_ROW )
{

    // ????????

}
```

I have a table with usernames that has 3 columns: "Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, timeStamp INT, Msg TEXT"

I want to get the msgs that are the difference of server time and last connection from the client ( serverTime - diff->tv_sec )

Comment: What is `sn` and why do you need to interpolate it in the query? Use query parameters instead of `snprintf`. Use [`sqlite3_column_*`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) to get query results.

Comment: Take a look at `sqlite3_column_xxx` family of functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "Msg" is TEXT. So in while loop you can call "sqlite3_column_text()"

```
while( sqlite3_step( res ) == SQLITE_ROW )
{
   const char *msg = sqlite3_column_text(res, 0);
   //Use msg
}
```

To get the proper result, make sure that `commands` i.e. your sql query is proper.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I researched a little about those functions, Thanks